# What is wrong with my use of regex?

Tags: regex, bash

my situation is this - I have a file:

```
this line(5)
that line(6)
another line(9)
one more(88)
last line(156)
```

I need to change the values in brackets from that to:

```
this line(1)
that line(2)
another line(3)
one more(4)
last line(5)
```

Basically, make the values ordered starting from 1.

Now, here's my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE=$1
COUNT=0
echo "Working with $FILE"

if [ -f $FILE ]; then
while read -r line; do 
    echo ${line/\([0-9]{1,3}\)/\($COUNT\)};
     let COUNT++;
  done < $FILE
else
  echo "File does not exist!"
fi
```

Here's what I get:

```
this line(5))/(0)}
that line(6))/(1)}
another line(9))/(2)}
one more(88))/(3)}
last line(156))/(4)}
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I specify in regex a number of artbitrary length?

Much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks all your help, I ended up utilizing a solution most similar to Drake's edit response, thank you all for your help though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your echo line to this:

```
echo ${line%%\([0-9]*\)}\($COUNT\)
```

**Edit:** The pattern replacement versions works as well, assuming there isn't parentheses with numbers anywhere else in the line - to use the pattern replacement and make sure that it only looks at the end of the line, use a `%` char after the first `/` separator, like so:

```
echo ${line/%\([0-9]*\)/\($COUNT\)}
```

Answer (score 1):

`echo ${line/([0-9]*)/($COUNT)};`

Your original had `{}` (not supported for some reason), and the `}` ended the variable. The fact that `()`'s are also not supported (at least here) means we don't have to escape them either.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `${line/([0-9]*)/($COUNT)}` is not quite right: the pattern `[0-9]*` means a digit followed by zero or more *arbitrary* characters -- not restricted to digits. Example

```
line='foo(1abc)'
COUNT=2
echo ${line/([0-9]*)/($COUNT)}
```

outputs `foo(2)`

The equivalent [bash pattern](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching) for the regex `[0-9]+` is the extended pattern `+([0-9])`

```
shopt -s extglob
echo ${line/(+([0-9]))/($COUNT)}
```

Comment: Interesting note, I didn't know + signs had any use in regex. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative approach using `cat -n` to print the line numbers with the line, and `sed` to substitute the line number into the parentheses:

```
cat -n $FILE | sed 's/^ *\([0-9]*\)\t\(.*\)([0-9]*)/\2(\1)/'
```

I was able to get your solution to work by changing the regex line to the following:

```
echo ${line/([0-9]*)/($COUNT)};
```

I could not get the repetition range to work there though.